# How can I show name and email?

Tags: php, mysql

With this code I am showing count of found users, but I also want to show name and email. Please improve my code. How can I show all details of counted rows? I don't know how. Can you please help me?

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mlm");
$i = 1;
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="select count('$username') from user where under_referral = '$username'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// display records in a table
echo '<div style="overflow-x:auto;">';
echo "<table>";
// set table headers
echo "<tr><th>Level</th><th>User Count</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>$i</th><th>" .$row[0]. "</th><th><a href='level1.php'>View</a> </th>";

echo "</tr>";
$i++;
echo "</table>";
echo '</div>';
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Which display are you expecting here ? Usually you would show user count once, then detailed users

Comment: i want to show counted rows data means if row count is 2 then want to show 2 rows username email etc.

Comment: But not the total amount of users ?

Comment: Rather than fetching count in our SQL Query, fetch all the data matching your search criteria. Then display it using while loop. To get the count, either you can get the count of the fetched array, or create your own counter. What I assume that you need the count only to be able to display exact number of users as fetched, so while loop would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

First just select everything you need at once with your query :

```
$sql="select name, email from user";
```

Then loop over your results with :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { [...]
```

Finally get data from each row :

```
$name = $row['name'];
```

If needed, you can get the row count with :

```
$number_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: You literally wrote in your post : "by this code i am showing count of find users but i also want to show name and email please improve ". So what are you expecting exactly ?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "counted rows data"? What I understand is that the rows that you have counted using SQL Query based on certain criteria. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

is easy :

```
$sql="select count('$username') as count,name,email from user where under_referral = '$username'";
```